# Making source command available for www-data user for virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

How can I make the source command available for the www-data user for virtualenvwrapper? I need to use source so that I can use the mkvirtualenv command. In my php script run by the www-data user, I already sudo chsh -s /bin/bash and gave permissions for www-data to execute /bin/bash

Some things I've tried in my PHP script

```
/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh (creates the .virtualenvs folder but doesn't make mkvirtualenv available)

. ./virtualenvwrapper.sh (creates the .virtualenvs folder but doesn't make mkvirtualenv available)

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper (source not found, but if it works it will make mkvirtualenv available)
```

Comment: Eh? `source` is only available after a copy of bash is *already running*, since it's a shell built-in, not a general-purpose UNIX command. How exactly are you starting that shell?

Comment: Moreover, `source` is a shell builtin only for bash (well, bash and some other extended shells, but *not* baseline POSIX sh) -- so if it's not found, that indicates that you aren't already in/running bash.

Comment: shell is started when a git webhook calls php script under the www-data user, i'm running the source command inside the script, so i don't think i'm already running bash

Comment: From a PHP script? Show your (PHP) code, then. If it's calling `system()`, for instance, that's implicitly invoking `sh -c`, which would explain why you can't use bash extensions.

Comment: `chsh` changes `/etc/passwd`, but that controls which *login* shell is in use; it doesn't impact noninteractive uses.

Comment: ...short form: The details of *exactly* where/how the shell where you're getting this error is invoked matter, and to be answerable, the question needs to include them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Nice note [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691023/making-source-command-available-for-www-data-user-for-virtualenvwrapper#comment74428358_43691023).

Comment: `I need to use source .. use the mkvirtualenv command`. I wonder if this is the right approach. You may read [\[this\]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170499/25919)